# Question about the uniqueness of integral curves (on a manifold)

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

In John Lee's discussion of integral curves, he managed to confuse me when it comes to the uniqueness of integral curves.

**In Example 9.1:**

With standard coordinates $(x,y)$ on the manifold $\mathbb{R}^2 $, and vector field $V = \frac{\partial}{\partial x}$ he computes the integral curves to be $\gamma(t)=(a+t,b)$ for any constants $a$ and $b$.

> He then makes the following statement:
>
> "Thus there is a unique integral curve starting at each point of the plane, and thus the images of different integral curves are either identical or disjoint."
>
> I am confused about what he means by this statement. In particular, the curves $\gamma: (-1,1) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ and $\tilde{\gamma}:(-2,2) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ both defined by the formula $t \mapsto (a+t,b)$ are two different curves (because their domains are different) and their images are not disjoint, nor are they the same.
>
> Later on in his proof of proposition  9.13 he makes a statement about "unique" integral curves. Based on my confusion of the previous statement, I am confused about the meaning of this.

Comment: He intends uniqueness once you think about the maximal domain of definition for the integral curve. :)

Comment: @TedShifrin Thanks, but I still don't understand the statement about the images of different curves either being identical or disjoint.

Comment: By integral curve he means the *maximal* integral curve with given initial conditions. So the integral curves are all lines parallel to the $x$-axis. As such, they are disjoint (unless you start at two different points on the same line, in which case the two integral curves are identical — not as parametrized curves, but as geometric subsets of the plane).

Comment: @TedShifrin Thanks Ted, it wasn't clear from his discussion, but I understand now.